# Express.js - GET for static files is failing for Mozilla

Tags: node.js, express, static, mozilla

I am a newbie to express, trying to serve an html file through express static mechanism. The following code shows the html file correctly in Microsoft Edge on Windows 10 but with Mozilla I get the error `Cannot GET /designer.html/` and the URL automatically changes to `http://localhost:3000/designer.html/` from `http://localhost:3000/designer.html`

I just want to know if I am doing something stupid, or this is genuinely a bug.

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

let dir = path.join(__dirname, 'views');
app.use(express.static(dir));

app.listen(3000, () => {
   console.log('Designer listening on port 3000.');
});
```

Comment: The URL change is most likely just a browser behaviour because you aren't specifying a sub URL, so it's removing the extra `/` not really something to get concerned about. I presume `designer.html` exists under the `views` folder?

Comment: @James correct. Remember, I can see it with Microsoft Edge.